# cleos host not found problem

Tags: api

I use docker cleos as below instruction:
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart
Before the cleos command works fine, but recently the cleos only works for read type, when I run "cleos system buyram" or simillar command, there is error as below:
Error 3200004: fail to resolve host
Error Details:
Error resolving "api.helloeos.com.cn:${url}" : Host not found (non-authoritative), try again later

I tried serveral API node, not work.
The client version seems lower than server. any idea how to fix this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would recommend upgrading your client to match the version of the servers, since there could be a mismatch in the format or structure of the data passed around or something like that.

Secondly, how are you specifying the host? This might also depend on your version of `cleos`, but if you're using a recent version, you would need to use something like

```
cleos --url https://api1.eosdublin.io <THE REST OF YOUR COMMAND>
```

so make sure you're specifying the parameter in the right way and including the `http` part (ideally `https`).

Good luck, and if it still doesn't work please add more details to your question so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your path environment per below link might work, eosio commands will be found then:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4771

Alternatively add $USER to docker might resolve the problem:

`sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER`

Reboot & retry